# Identifying and processing messages through Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-xe7

Consider a case where one manages to stack multiple KeyPress messages within a queue by swiftly typing 'ABC'.

Is there a way to identify and process a certain keypress message of one of the characters among the stack? I want to process the keyPress message of 'A' then go do something else before processing the keyPress messages of B and C.

Using "PeekMessage" i can't seem to isolate those 3 messages from each other.
Calling  PeekMessage (vMsg, Handle, WM_CHAR, WM_CHAR, PM_REMOVE), all 
messages are getting processed and removed at once.

Comment: You can't. In windows keyboards are processed by an IME. You can't make this change in the processing at the application message loop level. If you want to get that deep in the loop, write your own IME, which you CAN do.

Comment: What's your actual problem? If we knew that we might be able to give you a viable solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have an edit control residing within a grid. This control accepts item codes. Upon hitting 'enter' within the edit itself, i want to grab and "kill" it's keypress message and pass the key to the keypress event of the parent grid instead. 
This works just fine if you don't have accumulated messages in your queue, but since now i started using QRCodes - which autogenerate set of barcodes in a swift manner - when it's time to call PeekMessage within the keypress event of the 'Enter', there are 2-3 stacked messages over it which all are getting processed, hence my problem.

Comment: @Johny That's still not terribly clear.  What is the problem?

Comment: If I understand you right, your QR reader spits out a stream of characters terminated with a #13 ('Enter') and you want to react on that #13. Why do you need to mess around with `PeekMessage`? You can use the `OnKeypress` event of the edit control and check for the `var Key: Char` being #13, then do what you need to do and optionally assign `#0` to the `Key` to prevent further processing. Maybe I have misunderstood you?

Comment: You can also get at any message that is in the applications  message queue through Application.OnMessage.  If you don't want the keystroke to funnel down to the components...just change the Handled to true.   Make sure you are only looking at these message when you need to be...like when the grid has focus...take a peek at function TApplication.ProcessMessage(var Msg: TMsg): Boolean;  this is the work horse of your Message Queue.